# Bootstrap :: How to position an object within a row without using magins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, position

**[SOLVED]**

It's with `col-lg-push-5` etc

---

I'm using the bootstrap grid and I have got 2 objects (as seen below) and I want to center them in the row but can't use margins in CSS, otherwise it won't work in xs sizes. Is there any other workaround this? Thanks!

Code (standard bootstrap classes):

```
<div class="row">
                <form class="navbar-form search-bar" role="search">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" placeholder="Pesquisar"><button class="btn-group glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                </form>

        <div class="btn-group login col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Login
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
```

[image]

Comment: would you be able to use the class "text-center" or <center></center>?

Comment: No, not really but thanks.